# why does ruby give me a different answer to the 'which' command

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to point to an executable path and I tried using this in IRB:

```
%x( which wkhtmltopdf )
#"/home/james/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/wkhtmltopdf\n"
```

but when i type in the command in the command line I get:

```
 % which wkhtmltopdf  
 #/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

I suppose this is 2 questions:

1) why is ruby giving a different answer?

2) is there a way to get the command line answer in ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the ruby environment you are executing inside the context of the Bundler, which effectively overrides the path as a login variable inheriting from rbenv.

It looks like you have previously run `gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary`. This will override any system installs you are using on the path.

Check out [Login Shell Blogpost](http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766103-a-unix-shell-in-ruby-part-3-a-login-shell-and-the-path) for more information.

If you started a new shell, it might not inherit the rbenv environment:

```
%x(bash -l which wkhtmltopdf)
```

Alternatively you could get all the instances on the path and then filter out the results so that it doesn't contain the rbenv. (Exact code is untested)

```
all_binaries = %x(which -a wkhtmltopdf).split

original_binary = ""

all_binaries.each do |bin|
  if not s.contains? "rbenv"
    original_binary = bin

    # Will break on the first instance which isn't within the rbenv.
    break 
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks, bash -l does indeed give the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve 2)

```
`which wkhtmltopdf`
#"/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf\n"
```